# HAProxy Rewrite - Modify Query String

Tags: haproxy

I need to configure our HAProxy 1.5 server to rewrite a specific query string value to a new value, in a long URL. In the example below, dc needs to be changed from 12345 to 54321. I was planning to do this in the backend configuration:

Original URL: `http://www.domain.com/dl?dc=12345&pid=1234&other=1234&someother=1234`

Re-written URL: `http://www.domain.com/dl?dc=54321&pid=1234&other=1234&someother=1234`

I tried the following and I'm getting a 400 error from the server:

```
reqirep (.dc=)12345(.) \1\54321\2
```

And another I tried:

```
reqirep ([^\ ]*dc=)12345(.*) \1\54321/\2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Mike

In response -

So - I should be trying to modify the "request line" which would look like this:

GET /dl?dc=12345&pid=1234&other=1234&someother=1234 HTTP/1.1

Can you suggest syntax?

Comment: Your configuration line looks syntactically incorrect. Please double-check if that's indeed what you tried. Also include any relevant log entries and error messages you may have received.

Comment: Sorry - I corrected the syntax errors - bc should have been dc

Answer (score 0):

According to the [HAProxy manual section on reqirep](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.4.html#reqirep) the search regular expression must match the entire HTTP request line. Neither of the regular expressions you quoted will do that. For details see the [HAProxy manual section about the request line](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.4.html#1.2.1) which describes its format and should make it clear what you need to match.